# Setting the initial state of an RNN represented as a Keras sequential model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

How do I set the *initial state* of the recurrent neural network `rnn` constructed below?

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, SimpleRNN
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

rnn = Sequential([SimpleRNN(3), Dense(1)])
```

I'd like to specify the **initial state** of the first layer before fitting the model with `model.fit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [tf.keras.layers.RNN documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/RNN), you can specify the initial states *symbolically* using the argument `initial_state` or *numerically* by calling the function `reset_states`.

Symbolic specification means you need to add the initial states as a input to your model. Here is an example I adapted from the [Keras tests](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/70d7d07bd186b929d81f7a8ceafff5d78d8bd701/keras/layers/lstm_test.py#L187):

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, SimpleRNN, Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

timesteps = 3
embedding_dim = 4
units = 3

inputs = Input((timesteps, embedding_dim))
# initial state as Keras Input
initial_state = Input((units,))
rnn = SimpleRNN(units)
hidden = rnn(inputs, initial_state=initial_state)
output = Dense(1)(hidden)

model = Model([inputs] + [initial_state], output)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
              optimizer=tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer())
```

And once your model is defined, you can perform training as follows:

```
num_samples = 2

inputs = np.random.random((num_samples, timesteps, embedding_dim))
# random initial state as additional input
some_initial_state = np.random.random((num_samples, units))
targets = np.random.random((num_samples, units))
model.train_on_batch([inputs] + [some_initial_state], targets)
```

Note that this approach requires you to use the [Functional API](https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/). For Sequential models, you will need to use a *stateful* RNN, specify a `batch_input_shape`, and call the `reset_states` method:

```
input_shape = (num_samples, timesteps, embedding_dim)
model = Sequential([
    SimpleRNN(3, stateful=True, batch_input_shape=input_shape), 
    Dense(1)])

some_initial_state = np.random.random((num_samples, units))
rnn = model.layers[0]
rnn.reset_states(states=some_initial_state)
```