# How to read the initial state of an RNN in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I would like to see the initial condition used by an arbitrary Keras model. In the example below I set the initial state of the first unit to 0.123 in the first batch. But the output when I call the `rnn(...)` function starts one timestep later (when the unit activity is at 1.123 due to the bias of one) and does not return the initial condition.

Is there a way to make it show the initial condition?

Sample code below:

```
SEED=42
tf.random.set_seed(SEED)
np.random.seed(SEED)

timesteps = 3
embedding_dim = 4
units = 2
num_samples = 5

input_shape = (num_samples, timesteps, embedding_dim)
model = Sequential([
SimpleRNN(units, stateful=True, batch_input_shape=input_shape, return_sequences=True, activation="linear", 
          recurrent_initializer="identity", bias_initializer="ones"), 
Dense(1)])

some_initial_state = np.ones((num_samples, units))
some_initial_state[0,0] = 0.123
rnn = model.layers[0]
rnn.reset_states(states=some_initial_state)

some_initial_state, rnn(np.zeros((num_samples, timesteps, embedding_dim)))
```

Whose output is:

```
(array([[0.123, 1.   ],
    [1.   , 1.   ],
    [1.   , 1.   ],
    [1.   , 1.   ],
    [1.   , 1.   ]]),
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(5, 3, 2), dtype=float32, numpy=
 array([[[1.123    , 2.       ],
     [2.1230001, 3.       ],
     [3.1230001, 4.       ]],

    [[2.       , 2.       ],
     [3.       , 3.       ],
     [4.       , 4.       ]],

    [[2.       , 2.       ],
     [3.       , 3.       ],
     [4.       , 4.       ]],

    [[2.       , 2.       ],
     [3.       , 3.       ],
     [4.       , 4.       ]],

    [[2.       , 2.       ],
     [3.       , 3.       ],
     [4.       , 4.       ]]], dtype=float32)>)
```

Note that I am using `rnn.reset_states(...)` to set the initial state of the network, as explained in [Setting the initial state of an RNN represented as a Keras sequential model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63044445/setting-the-initial-state-of-an-rnn-represented-as-a-keras-sequential-model)

Comment: I think Keras initializes a zero vector as the `initial_state`. See [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a4dfb8d1a71385bd6d122e4f27f86dcebb96712d/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L3001) method in the source code.

Comment: Hi, @ShubhamPanchal, yes, normally it does. But I'm using `rnn.reset_states(...)` to initialize, as explained in this other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63044445/setting-the-initial-state-of-an-rnn-represented-as-a-keras-sequential-model

Comment: To initialize to *nonzero* values, specified in `some_initial_state`

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get the initial states by performing the inverse computation of the RNN cell. In this case, your are using a `SimpleRNNCell` and the forward computation is implemented in the [call method](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/06b04aeb745c90c5368be02928b08cc7fd592659/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L1367). Here is a possible implementation:

```
def get_rnn_initial_state(rnn_layer, rnn_input=None, rnn_output=None):

    # Get the kernel, recurrent_kernel, and bias variables
    kernel = rnn_layer.variables[0]
    recurrent_kernel = rnn_layer.variables[1]
    bias = rnn_layer.variables[2]

    if rnn_input is None:
        rnn_input = np.zeros(rnn_layer.input_shape)

    if rnn_output is None:
        rnn_output = rnn_layer(rnn_input)

    # Calculate hidden state
    h = rnn_input @ kernel.numpy() + bias.numpy()

    # Calculate pre-activation using the inverse of the activation function
    if rnn_layer.activation == tf.keras.activations.linear:
        pre_activation = rnn_output
    # inverse for other activation functions... 

    # Calculate the inverse of `output = h + backend.dot(prev_output, self.recurrent_kernel)`
    prev_output = (pre_activation - h) @ tf.linalg.inv(recurrent_kernel)

    # Get the first timesteps for each sample
    initial_state = prev_output[:, 0, :]    
    return initial_state

some_input = np.zeros((num_samples, timesteps, embedding_dim))
initial_state = get_rnn_initial_state(rnn, some_input, rnn_output)
assert np.allclose(some_initial_state, initial_state)
initial_state
```

Output:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(5, 2), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0.12300003, 1.        ],
       [1.        , 1.        ],
       [1.        , 1.        ],
       [1.        , 1.        ],
       [1.        , 1.        ]], dtype=float32)>
```

Since you are using a *stateful* RNN, you need to provide the input/output pairs corresponding to the initial state. If you just want to get the current state, then you can just use the `states` property:

```
state = rnn.states
```

Comment: "when need to provide the input/output pairs" is there a word missing?

Comment: you did not define `some_input` here

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I edited to fix the issues.

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense. I was looking for a way that would not involve doing the reverse computation, but just making Keras return it. As I wrote, "when I call the rnn(...) function starts one timestep later (...) and does not return the initial condition. Is there a way to make it show the initial condition?". Maybe the answer is "no, Keras doesn't do that"?